# socket.io not registering when user connects

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My problem here is that when someone connects to the page, it is supposed to print `'a user connected'` on the command line using node.js But that message is never shown so its not registering when a user visits the page (all being done in localhost). I'll post some code below and maybe you can find the issue and help me out?

JSON:

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.9.5",
    "socket.io": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/Users/kavehkhorram/Desktop/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>var socket = IO();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<script src="/Users/kavehkhorram/Desktop/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This is the correct (default) url where socket.io's client's apis are exposed (via http) by the node module.

Comment: Still no success, but under the /socket.io directory there is no socket.io.js file, but only a index.js file. The reason why my original source was so long is because i could only find socket.io.js under the /socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/ directory.

Comment: This file doesn't exist physically on this folder, socket.io serves it itself by default at this location. If your path works, have you tried `var socket = io.connect()` instead of `IO()` ? (check your console for errors like `IO is not defined`)

Comment: Ah I got it, in my JS file the variable was called 'io' (lowercase), but I was calling it using uppercase letters inside the 'index.html' file. Changing that and adding the '.connect()' seems to have fixed my issue!